# Decide whether this integration $\displaystyle \int ^\infty _ 0 \dfrac{x}{1+x^2\cos x} dx$ converges or diverges

Tags: integration, analysis, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

\begin{equation}
\int ^\infty _ 0 \dfrac{x}{1+x^2\cos x} dx
\end{equation}

I don't know how to prove if this integration is convergent or divergent.

My first idea is to find another function and do a limit comparison with $\dfrac{x}{1+x^2\cos x}$ at $x= \infty$, but I couldn't find a suitable function to do that.

Then, I tried to find whether $\dfrac{x}{1+x^2\cos x}$  this function is always less than another function or whether it is always greater than another function. However, since $\cos $ is oscillating between 1 and -1, I failed

I also tried to "split" this integral by only considering some intervals on which $\cos$ is greater than 0 or is less than zero (something like $\int ^\frac{\pi}{2} _ 0 \frac{x}{1+x^2\cos x} dx + \int ^\frac{3\pi}{2} _ \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{x}{1+x^2\cos x} dx+...$) As a result, I still can't figure it out.

Even though I can prove this the absolute value of $\dfrac{x}{1+x^2\cos x}$ is divergent, but it also seems not to be helpful.

Thus, any helps? Thanks!

---

Edit:(The integration is wrong, please dismiss this edition)
I tried integration by parts:
\begin{equation}
\displaystyle \int ^\infty _ 0 \dfrac{x}{1+x^2\cos x} dx = \dfrac{x^2}{2(1+x^2\cos x)}|^{\infty} _{0} + \dfrac{1}{2}\int^\infty_0\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2\cos x)^2} dx
\end{equation}

This function's absolute value is divergent, by writing the right hand side integration to be
\begin{equation}
\int^\infty_0\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2\cos x)^2} dx =\int^\infty_0|\frac{x}{(1+x^2\cos x)}|^2 dx
\end{equation}

Thus $\int^\infty_0\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2\cos x)^2} dx $ is divergent to infinity at $x= \infty$

And
$\dfrac{x^2}{2(1+x^2\cos x)}$ oscillates at positive infinity and negative infinity

As a result, I think this integration doesn't converge

Is this a reasonable argument?

Comment: There is a problem with the increment from $0$ to $\infty$ as the denominator vanishes at infinitely many points. Perhaps you can give a special meaning to that increment in order to save the reasoning.

Comment: Your integration by parts can't be right.

Comment: The second integral term is wrong, you missed the derivative of $1+x^2\cos x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The denominator of the integrand has infinitely many zeros of order $1$. For example, at $1.863\ldots$.

So already $\int_0^{1.863\ldots}f(x)\,dx$ is infinite. The fact that later, infinities of opposite sign come about does not help make the full integral convergent.